# How to use this SQL UPDATE query in VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net

Here textbox11 contains a float value and combo box contains a string do i have to put text or selected item

```
cmd.CommandType = "UPDATE BALANCE SET OBBALANCE =  '"& TextBox11.Text &"' WHERE     CUSTOMERNAME = "& ComboBox1.Text & " "
```

It gives the following error:

```
Operator '&' is not defined for string " UPDATE BALANCE SET OBBALANCE = " and type 'DataRowView'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead you should use parameters, as they are both escaped for sql injections and make more neat datapassing:

```
cmd.CommandType = " UPDATE BALANCE SET OBBALANCE =  @NEWBALANCE WHERE CUSTOMERNAME = @CUSTOMERNAME"
```

and add parameterwithvalue for:

```
"@NEWBALANCE", TextBox11.Text
"@CUSTOMERNAME", ComboBox1.Text
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Comment: hey sorry to ask how to add parameter i am new to do sorry i dont wanna make you tensed actually i odnt knw abt that how to add parameter value

Comment: ya i seen but still i cant understand how to give or add parameter i had copied u r line that update cmd line and pasted and the next two things it shows error so how to declare it i cant understand can u explain

Answer (score 0):

1. I would not recommend using inline SQL query. Use Stored Procedure instead and pass parameters.
2. If you pass Text - you will get the display value... if you want to pass the underlying value, then use "SelectedValue"
3. However to resolve your issue, use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The available CommandTypes are

StoredProcedure
TableDirect
Text

It looks like you want to set your CommandType to Text and set your CommandText to what you have there.

That said, I agree with stefan's answer about parameters.